# Django FileField passing the files

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

OK, I have a model for `TemporaryFile` and the final file model (`File`) they have different storage functions (destinations). I'm saving the first model and after some time I need to pass the file to the second model, so that it saves the file its way. For now I'm doing something like that:

```
attachments.append(File(file=temp.file.file, message=self))
```

But it just passes over the URL. Which isn't what I'd like to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions has been answered here: [copy file from one model to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5764803/1349940).

Spoilers: it requires StringIO.