# Django FileField manual copying

Tags: django

```
class ModelFile(models.Model):
    ufile = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
```

And I have some management command and inside:

```
...
my_file = ModelFile.objects.create(ufile='/home/myfile.txt')
```

And I have objects instance, but I don't see myfile.txt in my files directory in project? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that creating a new modelfile with just a file path doesn't actually duplicate the file - it just links to the one that already exists. To actually duplicate the file you can use ContenFile like in the SO answer here: [Duplicate Model Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10885760/3345051)

Answer (score 0):

> And I have [the model] instance, but I don't see myfile.txt in my files directory in project?

That's right. `Model.create` creates an instance of the model, with all the field values you specified.

There is nothing in your code that would create a corresponding file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files import File

instance = ModelFile.objects.create()
with open('/home/filename.txt', 'w') as file:
    instance.ufile.save('filename.txt', File(file))
```