# Django view doesn't save model instances but running the data processing functions correctly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a function that process images that are uploaded by users. I made a view that when entered apply the function on the uploaded images.

## models.py

```
class UploadedImages(models.Model):
    patient =           models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images')
    pre_analysed =      models.FileField(upload_to = user_directory_path ,
                                            verbose_name = 'Image')

class Processed(models.Model):
    uploaded_image = models.ForeignKey(UploadedImages,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='processed')
    analysedimage = models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path,
                                      verbose_name='analysed Image', blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def AnalysedDetails(request,pk=None):
    Uimage = get_object_or_404(models.UploadedImages,pk=pk)
    analysed = models.Processed(uploaded_image=Uimage,analysedimage=main(Uimage.pre_analysed.path))
    analysed.save()
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

but when i check the admin page to see the model it only saves the uploaded image and doesn't save the processed one and when I check the directory i find that only the uploaded image field is saved.

I tried

`analysed=models.Processed(uploaded_image=Uimage.pre_analysed,analysedimage=main(Uimage.pre_analysed.path))`

but it returns

> Cannot assign "":
>   "Processed.uploaded_image" must be a "UploadedImages" instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create new object, theres simple way, using `.create()`,
see this how to [create object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)
so, it would be
`analysed = models.Processed.objects.create(...)`
and you don't need `save()` method if you use this way

to save ImageField programmatically, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764803/copy-file-from-one-model-to-another/10885760#10885760)

Comment: I found out that the problem is with the function as it saves the file in the same path with a different name 
look at this question for more info and btw thanks for your help really appreciate it.